# click event not firing within a bootstrap radio button group

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I create radio buttons dynamically and using a on() function try to capture the click and do something with it.

As long as I used radio buttons it worked fine. I then encapsulated the radio buttons within a bootstrap markup to turn it into a button group - now when I click the button the click event never fires. No idea what I'm missing!

Here's the code

the markup that's generated dynamically

```
 <div id="q_opt" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active" id="d_op_0"> <input id="q_op_0" name="op" type="radio" value="0">22%
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" id="d_op_1"> <input id="q_op_1" name="op" type="radio" value="1">19%
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" id="d_op_2"> <input id="q_op_2" name="op" type="radio" value="2">11%
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" id="d_op_3"> <input id="q_op_3" name="op" type="radio" value="3">42%
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" id="d_op_4"> <input id="q_op_4" name="op" type="radio" value="4">8%</label>
</div>
```

Here's the markup that selects the radio via a jQuery selector and checks if a click was fired

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio[id^="q_op_"]', function(event) {
    alert("click fired");
}
```

Is bootstrap interfering in some way - or am I missing some step? I'm staring at the code and my eyes aren't catching a mistake anymore. Any help / tips appreciated!

(PS - the radio buttons get converted to a nice looking button group, the buttons click and stay pressed on the ones clicked etc. so the behavior seems fine, except that the click isn't registered by on(..) )

Comment: You are using the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/): `'input:radio[id^="q_op_"]'` and i copied your code from above and it works for me - altough with not dynamically created radio-buttons but static ones. 
How do you create the radio-boxes dynamically and how do you fire the binding `$(document).on('click', ....)`
Also it seems that some braces are missing. Can you post more code?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the change handler instead because the click are happening in the label

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[id^="q_op_"]', function (event) {
    alert("click fired");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8sqU7/)

Comment: Arun - my code block was in the wrong place. Now the change function does fire... one stage done, there are more issues but I will mark you answer as it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked perfectly to me.

Comment: It also works if you listen for an input inside a class or id ```'#theID input'```.

Comment: Is this possible using the native `addEventListener`? I'm not sure what jQuery is doing under the hood, but I need to capture this event without jQuery.

Comment: Worked perfect for me! Thanks.

Comment: Works for me only on the first click. Subsequent clicks doesn't trigger the `onchange` event!  `onclick` on the `label` works all the time though.

Comment: I should note that this solution worked for me in Bootstrap 4. Something like `$("input[type=radio][name=particles-condition]").on("change", filter);` was basically perfect for me.

Answer (score 16):

I had a challenge with this too. But instead of putting the eventListeners on the radio buttons, I put them on the label i.e.:

```
$('#d_op_1').on("click",function(){ 
   alert("click fired"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use onchange() attribute of input.

```
<input id="3" name="option" type="radio" style="height: 15px;width: 15px;" onchange="alert('changed')">
```