# jQuery: perform specific action on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I have couple of radio buttons from **bootstrap** like below.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary">
 <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
 <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
 <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
</label>
</div>
```

How can I perform specific action for each radio button in jQuery?

for instance:

if option1 is checked -> load "html1.html"
if option2 is checked -> load "html2.html"

And I use this code to load an html code in specific div :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('#main-content').load('skill-temp.html');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: that title smelled wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is to have a data attribute in your input, guiding the jQuery load action. Something like:

```
 <input class="loadhtml" data-html="page1" type="radio" name="options" id="option1">
 <input class="loadhtml" data-html="page2" type="radio" name="options" id="option2">
 <input class="loadhtml" data-html="page3" type="radio" name="options" id="option2">
```

and then

```
 <script>
 $('input.loadhtml').on('change', function(){
    var data = $(this).data('html');
    $('#main-content').load(data + '.html');
 });
 </script>
```

edit

[A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAtw6/2/), with the only difference i alert(data) passed instead of calling load

Comment: I added your attributes to `<input>` but the code is not working!

Comment: It does work, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VAtw6/2/ i just use alert to check the values passed instead of load. Maybe you forgot / have different class in the inputs?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap radio buttons! does that make any difference? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: I just added a class to specify in which input(s) the function should run. If you have all inputs in, let's say, a <div class="myinputwrapper"> then you would change $('input.loadhtml') to $('.myinputwrapper input') and the function would run in all inputs that are children this element. The ones (classes) you have there in your html are most likely being used elsewhere too, so you must make it a little more specific

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('input[name="options"]').change(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+$/);
    $('#main-content').load('html'+num+'.html');
});
```

Comment: I had to write a jsfiddle to convince myself that change is not triggered by the radio that is clicked AND the radio that was checked before

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832568/click-event-not-firing-within-a-bootstrap-radio-button-group)

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[class^="loadhtml"]', function (event) {
 var data = $(this).data('html');
$('#main-content').load(data + '.html');
});
```

Add class="loadhtml" to each radio button

```
<div id="nav" class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input class="loadhtml" type="radio" data-html="Skills" name="options"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span> About
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input class="loadhtml" type="radio" name="options"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Skills
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input class="loadhtml" type="radio" name="options"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Education
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input class="loadhtml" type="radio" name="options"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Timeline
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input class="loadhtml" type="radio" name="options"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Hobbies</label>
```

Comment: or just `$(document).on('change', '.loadhtml', function()` or if the radios are always there and not loaded in the .load process, `$(".loadhtml").on('change', function()`

Comment: Then I would suggest you perhaps accepted http://stackoverflow.com/a/23561601/295783

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input:radio[name="options"]').change(
        function(){

            var id =this.id;
            if ( id  == 'option1') {
               // call html page 1
            }
             else if( id  == 'option2'){
              // call html page 2

             }    

        });
```

Comment: Very inelegant. And no need to check ":checked" since change is only triggered when the radio is clicked